# Create a summary report in team services for project/epic

Tags: azure-devops

I was inspired by the [One-Page PRD](https://www.atlassian.com/agile/requirements) mentioned on the Atlassian website.

How might I go about doing the same if I am using Team Services? For example, lets say I have an Epic and linked underneath that several features, user stories and acceptance criteria. Is it possible to create a "one pager" based on just this epic that summarizes all the items underneath it at a glance? (for example: lists the epic's description at the top, followed by all the user stories with description and current status, and acceptance criteria met or not met underneath?) It would be useful for distributing to non-technical product owners instead of having them wander through work item queries to get an overall picture of the project with some requirement detail, or to present to stakeholders during a meeting.

Most of the reporting options I am finding, such as the built in dashboards (and Power BI?) are mostly aggregate charting. It would be simpler to create what I need in SSRS, but my understanding is that is not available with Team Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said that the Team Services has built in dashboards and integrate with Power BI, but aren’t meet your requirement.

For your requirement, you can build a custom extension (e.g. [Dashboard widget](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-dashboard-widget)) with [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/overview) (can call rest api with VSS sdk, check dashboard widget sample for detail) to do the report.